# How do you click on an anchor link from your nav bar and change the content in your div without javascript?

Tags: html, css

I understand that normally when you click on a link from your nav bar another web page opens.

In my current personal project I only want to change the div content after I click on a link from the nav bar, this means the change is small and I know how important the DRY rule is so I am pretty confused here.

In this situation if I want to make this happen with only standard HTML, CSS and without javascript(not taught in class) the only option is to upload multiple version of the same HTML file with different div contents and link those with the anchor links in the nav bar in the index HTML file correct?

[image: What I am trying to do.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an [inline frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), or `<iframe>`.  This allows you to set up an area where context can appear, and you can link it directly to a specific frame.

For example:

```
<nav>
  <a href="https://example.com" target="main">Open in iframe</a>
</nav>

<iframe name="main" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

In this example, the link has the `target` set to `main`, which happens to be the `name` of the `iframe`.  Any link with the target matching the iframe's name will open up within that iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use CSS [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target). The idea is that you click a hashed link (like `#about`) and show the `HTML` fragment with the corresponding `id` via `CSS`, hiding everything not targeted.

```css
main>section {
  display: none;
}

:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>

<main>
  <section id="home">
    <h2>Welcome To My Homepage</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque veritatis obcaecati minima rerum doloribus expedita deleniti nesciunt voluptate quo, in, perferendis quibusdam sed quas quisquam recusandae adipisci, asperiores iure quod!</p>
  </section>

  <section id="about">
    <h2>My About Section</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque veritatis obcaecati minima rerum doloribus expedita deleniti nesciunt voluptate quo, in, perferendis quibusdam sed quas quisquam recusandae adipisci, asperiores iure quod!</p>
  </section>

  <section id="contact">
    <h2>My Contact Section</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque veritatis obcaecati minima rerum doloribus expedita deleniti nesciunt voluptate quo, in, perferendis quibusdam sed quas quisquam recusandae adipisci, asperiores iure quod!</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxogaLe0/)